# Deleting database objects in django - How do I correctly make a delete function?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm building my first solo django project and one of the stumbling blocks I've run into is creating a "delete function" so I can delete objects in the database. I've been looking at various tutorials for this but I'm getting slightly confused along the way. I'd really appreciate any advice on how to do this correctly in django. Here's what I've been working with so far.

I have a model called "Myteam" which looks like this...

```
class Myteam(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    QB = models.CharField(max_length=80, null=True)
    QBscore = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    RB1 = models.CharField(max_length=80, null=True)
    RB1score = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    RB2 = models.CharField(max_length=80, null=True)
    RB2score = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    WR = models.CharField(max_length=80, null=True)
    WR1score = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    WR2 = models.CharField(max_length=80, null=True)
    WR2score = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    TE = models.CharField(max_length=80, null=True)
    TEscore = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    D = models.CharField(max_length=80, null=True)
    Dscore = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    K = models.CharField(max_length=80, null=True)
    Kscore = models.IntegerField(null=True)
```

In my views.py, yesterday, I tried this out...

```
def delete_player(request, pk):
    player = Myteam.objects.get(pk=id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        player.delete()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index"))
    
    return render(request, 'game/index.html')
```

Here's my urls.py

```
path('delete_player/<str:pk>', views.delete_player, name="delete_player")
```

For the html, I was initially trying to have a button link to the delete_player function, but so many of the tutorials I've been looking at use a form with a submit, so I tried that out (this is only a small section of the original, much larger table).

```
<div>
    <form action="" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <table style="border: 1px solid black;">
        
        <tr>
            <td style="border: 1px solid black;">QB</td>
            <th style="border: 1px solid black;">{{ team.QB }} <input type="submit" name="Drop"></th>
            <th style="border: 1px solid black;"></th>
            <th style="border: 1px solid black;">{{ QBscore }}</th>
            <th style="border: 1px solid black;"></th>
        </tr>
       
      </table>
    </form>
    
</div>
```

Here's a screenshot of what's going on with the table/frontend. Basically, I want to be able to delete players from the Myteam model in the database. Ideally, I'm going to enable the buttons for this, the "submit" button is part of the above experiment that I recently tried that I can't get to work.
[Players in the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xvab.jpg)

Comment: Are there any errors ?

Comment: No, just nothing happens.

Comment: add a print statment in `def delete_player` and see if it appears in tthe console. BTW you want to check if the user requesting the view is the user who is deleted. otherwise anybody could come and delete all your users by just calling the url.

Comment: I only have the Myteam model right now.

Comment: @hansTheFranz Just tried putting in a print statement but it won't come up in the console.

Answer (score 0):

There is no link to your form and the view which is deleting the object. You can redirect user to your view when he clicks on the delete button(The form can be a simple prompt like do you want to delete).

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table style="border: 1px solid black;">
    
    <tr>
        <td style="border: 1px solid black;">QB</td>
        <th style="border: 1px solid black;">{{ team.QB }} <a href="{% url 'delete_player' pk=player.id %}">Delete</a></th>
        <th style="border: 1px solid black;"></th>
        <th style="border: 1px solid black;">{{ QBscore }}</th>
        <th style="border: 1px solid black;"></th>
    </tr>
   
  </table>
</form>
```

Or add action URL to your form

```
<form action ="delete_player/<str:pk>" methos = "POST">
...
</form>
```

JS for capturing PK

```
<script>
const ele =document.getElementById('idOFSubmitButton')
ele.addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
  document.myform.action = `delete_player/${e.target.pk}/`
  document.myform.submit()
})
</script>
```

The button in HTML should have an attribute PK which should be the ID of player you want to delete.

Ideally, I would go with the first option because you wouldn't want to delete objects if someone clicks on the button by mistake.

Comment: Good points. I tried it out but am getting the following error, NoReverseMatch at /game/
Reverse for 'delete_player' with keyword arguments '{'pk': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['game/delete_player/(?P<pk>[^/]+)$']

Comment: @user14593966 If you are going with the action URL. You will have to pass actual pk instead of just pk. You can capture the PK with JS.

Comment: @user14593966 I have added some code for capturing PK with JS in my original answer but I don't think this is a good way of doing I would suggest you look into generic class views and the first method I mentioned

Comment: thanks. I appreciate your help here. I'm not sure what you mean by "capturing PK" though.